# Angular dynamic and nested drop area not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

I have been working on a form builder using Angular CDK drag and drop, and I'm facing an issue with dynamic drop areas. I have successfully implemented drag and drop functionality without nested lists, but now I'm trying to create multiple drop areas by drop columns and try to drop inputs on those column area its not working.
Unfortunately, the nested drag areas are not functioning as expected.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone from the community could take a look at my issue and provide some guidance or insights on how to resolve it. Your expertise and assistance would be invaluable to me.

Thank you so much for your time and support. Looking forward to hearing from you.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vhbhta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fform-builder.service.ts)